$N, N^2, N^3$ when N has digits from 0 to 9 each exactly one!
$N$ has digits  from 0 to 9 each once,
$N^2$ has digits from 0 to 9 each twice,
$N^3$ has digits from 0 to 9 each three times,
I coded it and I see there is not any valid 10 digit number $N$ which meets criteria given in the problem.
how can we prove there is not any solution to this problem?

N^2  has exactly 20 digits and N^3 has exactly 30 digits!

Oh, right!  Sorry about that.  I'll delete.

Assuming your program is correct, you have proven it.  Proof by exhaustion is a fine technique.  I don't see any easier approach.

@Dominique:  No, the square of a number of ten digits has either $19$ or $20$ digits depending on whether there is a carry.  The cube has $28$ to $30$ digits.  As long as the $10$ digit number starts higher than $464$ it will carry to not start with $0$.

N has 10 digits from 0 to 9-included- and each digit is used once, N2 has 20 digits from 0-9 and each digit is used 2 times and N3 has 30 digits and the same constraint should be.

I need to have a proof because this question is the simple version of 30-60-90 digit problem, N has 30 digits and each digit from 0-9 is used exactly 3 times, in N2 they are used 6 times and in N3 they are used 9 times and it is impossible to get an output in a short time when you code it,  you know.

Arguments over whether square gas 19 or 20 digits and likewise for tge cube are useless. A properly constructed program for this problem will reject cases where the digit count misses the target, or simply require the first digits of the candidate to exceed those in the cube root of 100.

You can follow through my calculation to see if you expect a solution.  I suspect it will come out far less likely that you have one, but have not done it.  Where is the problem from?  When I searched for 30-60-90 problem everything was about right triangles.

The question is when N is a 30 digit number which has from 0-9 digits exactly 3 times, and when N is squared, the 60 digit number has each digit 6 times, -0 to 9- and when N is cubed, the 90 digit number has each digit exactly 9 times- 0 to 9.

Here is the question;
Find the smallest 30-digit integer N which contains each of the digits 0 to 9 three times, whose square is a 60-digit number which contains each of the digits 0 to 9 six times, and whose cube is a 90-digit number which contains each of the digits 0 to 9 nine times.

It comes from contestcen.com.

But, for the original problem, this appoach is insufficient, there are (4,38610^24) 30 digit numbers with the given constraint and the probability that a random 60 digit string has exactly 6 digits of each digit is about 2.222(10^-7) and for the cube numbers the probability is about 3.7510^-8.  So there are x10^17 square numbers  x* 10^9 cube numbers. Excuse me about the notation I used.

This can be extended to an interesting problem : Let us call a positive integer "balanced" if every digit from $0$ to $9$ occurs equally often. Then the challenge could be to find $N$ such that $N,N^2,N^3$ are all balanced (if such a positive integer $N$ exists at all) and in particular to find the smallest $N$ with this property.

I don't see an easy proof, but heuristically it is not surprising if we regard the digits as random.  You start with $10!=3,628,800$ numbers with $10$ distinct digits.  There are $\frac {20!}{2^{10}}$ strings of $20$ digits that have two of each digit, so the probability that a random $20$ digit string has exactly $2$ of each digit is $\frac {20!}{2^{10}10^{20}}\approx 2.3 \cdot 10^{-5}$ so we expect only $86$ successes for the square.  The probability that a random $30$ digits string has exactly $3$ of each digit is $\frac {30!}{6^{10}10^{30}}\approx 4.4 \cdot 10^{-6}$ so you expect $3.8 \cdot 10^{-4}$ successes.
As Michael Lugo points out the squares and cubes are all multiples of $9$ as are the equally distributed digit strings.  That increases the expected number by a factor of $9^2=81$, so we are closer to $1$ but still below.

However all the strings of digits involved have sums divisible by 9, which increases the expected number of successes.

Good approach, almost proof.
